# IIS7 responds with a 404 when extension is not listed in the Mime Types. Can't IIS simply serve the file as a default type?

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration

How do I configure IIS to return files whether or not they are listed in the Mime Types list? It doesn't make sense for IIS to return a 404 when the file exists.

Comment: All I could do was add each non-common file extension to Mime Types. That worked but you know it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Older versions of IIS had this built-in, but IIS 6.0+ does not.
If you want it to serve just any file regardless of having a registered MIME type:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click the Server, then open MIME Types in the Features View Pane.
3. Add from the Actions Pane
4. File name extension: `*`
5. MIME Type: `application/octet-stream` (if you want the browser to download the file) or `plain/text` (if you want the file displayed)
6. OK

Comment: This works perfectly and so obviously. I used content type text/plain though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use "." (a dot) as extension and create a MIME mapping.
https://forums.iis.net/t/1158170.aspx